# Any way to monitor load on a power outlet and receive notifications of usage?

Tags: electrical, home-automation, receptacle

My sump pump float sometimes sticks.  This is an issue because the pump can easily run dry and burn out, especially if we are away for an extended period of time.

Ideally I'm looking for something that the sump plugs in 'through' which will alert me via iphone/sms/email either:

a) if its running for too long (based on power draw) or
b) if it exceeds a certain electricity usage threshold within a period of time

I'm thinking B is more realistic than A, based on the available power monitor products on the market.

Once I receive the alert I would know the pump is likely stuck 'on' and then be able to toggle the outlet on and off via iPhone.

Belkin's [WeMo](http://www.belkin.com/us/wemo) does provides the on/off functionality but doesn't allow me to monitor or set alerts against usage.

Comment: I've seen some high-end solutions that provides live monitoring of the amperage of your entire panel per break, some people have modded the Kill-a-watt unit to do similar. Off the question now; you might want to look for something like a [Wayne Electronic Sump Pump Control](http://www.amazon.com/Wayne-Electronic-Sump-Control-Alarm/dp/B000H5RXZI). It doesn't rely on moving parts (float valve) and has a timer so the pump can only run for so long per cycle. Other alarm only devices are available but they don't help much if you're not physically there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and cheaper to either fix or replace the sump?

Comment: Even with a fixed sump I'd still want to be sure it wasn't going to happen again.

Comment: Looks like the ThinkEco Modlet will do the trick for monitoring at least: http://themodlet.com - it will monitor and track energy usage over time so I can see how often the sump pump is triggering

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Watts Up? .net](https://orders.wattsupmeters.com/store/product.php?productid=16147&cat=249&page=1) would work. I don't see the notification listed explicitly but the data is there so creating some threshold to notify you shouldn't be impossible. It may have monthly fees to use depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this from a z-wave supplier, MiCasaVerde, [Smart switch](http://micasaverde.com/smartswitch.php), which would plug inline for monitoring power usage.  You could couple it with a [smart outlet](https://shop.micasaverde.com/index.php/in-wall-switches/evolve-lom-15a-wall-receptacle.html)

I don't know much about the various programming capabilities, but with no-lease monitoring charges via your WiFi, checking in is easy.

Couple it with a leak monitor and a water powered sump backup and you should feel pretty safe

But really, shouldn't you spend money on fixing your pump setup, first.

Comment: I would agree with HerrBag, for the cost to get the Home Automation set up to actually monitor the 1 device and recieve alerts, it would be cheaper to fix the sump pump.